# Checkboxes in Form to javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a form with dynamic checkboxes based on MySQL data. On submit the DIV refreshes without blinking with JavaScript. I'm trying to send the form data to PHP for updating the MySQL but I constantly run into one error or another due to my lack of JavaScript knowledge. My current attempt (see below) gives the "TypeError: document.multipix_form.pix is undefined" error in FireBug.

```
function multipicupdate(php_file, purpose, where) {
    var request =  getXMLHTTP();        // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance
    var a = document.getElementById("optone").value ;
    var b = document.getElementById("table").value ;
    var boxes = document.multipix_form.pix.length
    txt = ""
    for (i = 0; i < boxes; i++) {
        if (document.multipix_form.pix[i].checked) {
            txt = txt + document.multipix_form.pix[i].value + " "
        }
    }

  var  the_data = 'purpose='+purpose+'&var1='+a+'&var2='+b+'&var3='+txt;
  request.open("POST", php_file, true);         // set the request
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(the_data);       // calls the send() method with datas as parameter
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

The form name is multipix_form. The three form inputs are optone (select), table (select), and pix[] (checkbox). The pix[] is dynamic as I said before. It is the passing of the checkbox data from JavaScript to php that has me stumped.
My form submit is :

```
<input type="button" onClick="multipicupdate('php/ajaxprocess.php', 'multipix', 'message_profile'); return false;" value="Save changes to this photo">
```

The ajaxprocess.php will take the form data and update MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged jQuery, here's a jQuery solution. You can simplify this code quite a lot. Firstly, you can use `serialize()` to create a querystring from the values of the inputs in that form. Then you can use `$.ajax` to send that information to the page you need. Try this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save changes to this photo" id="multipicupdate">
```

```js
$('#multipicupdate').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(), // change the selector as needed
        success: function(data) {
            $('#message_profile').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay, changed #myForm to #multipix_form (my form's id) and set the url to a php script that currently is only "<?php print_r($_POST); ?>" but I don't get the checkbox data. Did I miss something?

Comment: Going to assume that this is the correct answer and that my issue with the checkbox data not serializing is something else. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon after

```
var boxes = document.multipix_form.pix.length
```

and

```
txt = ""
```